# First container rendered have no data from api fetch in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Im fetching an api and the data is being stored in result state. list state is an array that consist an object with an id, result, and responseinput. addItem method pushes the object into arrayList and that is being pushed to list state. list state with a .map method is being rendered at the end in return inside a container after addItem() is called which is the submit button.

Only the first index of  `list state array` that was fetched from the api doesn't get the data that is stored in result and all the index after does have data from the api.
I tried setTimeout but it doesn't work. The .map method is at the return of a react component. I looked at the console and it seems that the first render, the api is being fetched and pending for a few second, but the container is already added to the webpage and thats why it doesnt have any data on. Been trying to figure out an entire day and cant find the solution.

```
export default function CreatePrompt() {
    const [responseInput, setResponseInput] = useState("");
    const [result, setResult] = useState("");
    const [list, setList] = useState([
        {
            id: 101,
            inputPrompt: "What is on your mind?",
            value: "You are on my mind.",
        }
    ]);

    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const getData = async () => {
            const data = {
                prompt: responseInput,
                temperature: 0.5,
                max_tokens: 64,
                top_p: 1.0,
                frequency_penalty: 0.0,
                presence_penalty: 0,
            };
            try {
                const response = await fetch('*********', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_USER_KEY}`
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
                if (response.ok) {
                    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
                    setResult(jsonResponse.choices[0].text)
                    setResponseInput(responseInput)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        getData()
    }

    const addItem = () => {
        if (responseInput !== '') {
            const promptObj = {
                id: Math.random(),
                inputPrompt: responseInput,
                value: result,
            }

            const arrayList = [...list];
            arrayList.push(promptObj);
            setList(arrayList);
            setResponseInput('');
        }
    }


    const deleteItem = (key) => {
        const arrayList = [...list]

        const updateList = arrayList.filter(item => item.id !== key);

        setList(updateList);
    }
```

```
    return (
        <div>
            <main className="ui container heading-container">
                <h1 id="heading">Fun With AI</h1>
                <p id="command-description">Hello, my name is GPT-3. Ask me to do something.</p>
                <div className="ui form">
                    <form className="field" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                        <label id="prompt-subheading">Enter Prompt</label>
                        <div className='ui input focus'>
                            <textarea
                                type='text'
                                value={responseInput}
                                onChange={(e) => setResponseInput(e.target.value)}>
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button
                            className="ui button blue right floated"
                            id="submit-button"
                            onClick={addItem}
                        >Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </main>
            <div className="ui container subheading-container">
                <h2 id="response-subheading">Responses</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                {list.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <div
                            className="ui container new-response-container"
                            key={item.id}
                        >
                            <div>
                                <button
                                    className="ui right floated button grey mini delete-button"
                                    onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}
                                >X
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="info-container">
                                <div className="prompt-container">
                                    <h3 className="response-title">Prompt:</h3>
                                    <p id="prompt-input">
                                        {item.inputPrompt}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="response-container">
                                    <h3 className="response-title">Response:</h3>
                                    <p id="response-result">{item.value}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }).reverse()}
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}
```

Comment: not your issue, but you don't need to `await jsonResponse.choices[0].text)` ... since `jsonResponse` is just a plain ol' javascript object parsed from the JSON returned by the request, so has no `Promise`s to `await`

Comment: Are you referring to rendering the `list` state? There is only the one element in the `list` state array, is there an issue rendering it? Are you trying to update the `list` state somewhere in your code that you haven't included in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Please edit your question to include all relevant code you are having an issue working with.

Comment: I can't find where do you use `addItem` or `setList` other than in `addItem`

Comment: @Bravo, yeah i did took that off, was testing if that solved my problem

Comment: @DrewReese the list state is rendered out as a container. It renders out fine, but the first container does not contain the api data but all the container after was able to display the data

Comment: @Konrad, ah sorry, i didnt list that part of the code on this post, but the addItem function is called after clicking the submit button. Just added in the code on my post

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are referring to as "containers". Are you referring to the mapped `list` array that you are rendering?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, the container is the mapped list array. sorry for the confusion

Comment: The form invokes its `onSubmit` handler at the same time and completely independently from the submit button's `onClick` handler that is calling `addItem`. It seems you want to, or should, call `addItem` from the `onSubmit` callback once the data has been fetched.

Comment: @DrewReese after changing from ```onClick``` to ```onSubmit```, it doesnt render it out to the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can tell, it seems you are wanting the user to enter some value into the `textarea` input that is used in the `onSubmit` handler, then use `onSubmit` makes a POST request with the entered data and `addItem` to update the `list` state with the entered `responseInput` and resolved response value.

The issue with the current code is that both `onSubmit` (*via the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler*) ***and*** `addItem` (*via the submit button's `onClick` handler*) are invoked simultaneously. In other words, `addItem` uses the unupdated `result` state value before `onSubmit` has made the POST request and received a response.

## Solution

Call `addItem` or handle that logic synchronously in the `onSubmit` callback handler. I also suggest using a utility function to generate GUIDs, just about anything is better than `Math.random()`.

Note that this suggested solution removes completely the intermediate `result` state ***and*** `addItem` function since the response value is handled entirely in the `onSubmit` handler.

Example:

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

export default function CreatePrompt() {
  const [responseInput, setResponseInput] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      id: uuidV4(),
      inputPrompt: "What is on your mind?",
      value: "You are on my mind.",
    }
  ]);

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const getData = async () => {
      const data = {
        prompt: responseInput,
        temperature: 0.5,
        max_tokens: 64,
        top_p: 1.0,
        frequency_penalty: 0.0,
        presence_penalty: 0,
      };

      try {
        const response = await fetch('*********', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_USER_KEY}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          const jsonResponse = await response.json();

          const promptObj = {
            id: uuidV4(),
            inputPrompt: responseInput,            // save current prompt input
            value: jsonResponse.choices[0].text,   // save resolved response value
          }

          setList(list => [...list, promptObj);    // enqueue list state update
          setResponseInput('');                    // clear out prompt value
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    if (responseInput) {
      getData();
    }
  };
```

Remove the submit button's `onClick` handler. Note that even though `type="submit"` is the default `type` attribute value, it is best to be explicit anyway by specifying `type="submit"` so it is *overtly* clear to any future readers of your code that the button submits a form.

```
<main className="ui container heading-container">
  <h1 id="heading">Fun With AI</h1>
  <p id="command-description">Hello, my name is GPT-3. Ask me to do something.</p>
  <div className="ui form">
    <form className="field" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label id="prompt-subheading">Enter Prompt</label>
      <div className='ui input focus'>
        <textarea
          type='text'
          value={responseInput}
          onChange={(e) => setResponseInput(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        className="ui button blue right floated"
        id="submit-button"
        type="submit"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but the solution is not working. Not sure if i mentioned it previously, but after the user type in the text area and click the submit button, it fetch the data and it supposed to create a container that display the original prompt from the text area with the response(the data that is fetched from the api). That container is rendered on the web page and stays there. Any new prompt will create another container and display it on the page which is why I have the ```addItem``` method. User can manually delete the container afterward as well, the ```deleteItem```  method

Comment: The ```addItem``` method is not part of the ```onSubmit``` method. Thats why I have the ```onClick``` on the button to call the addItem method and to render the container of all the data from```list state``` into the webpage.

Comment: @Jason Ok. Can you explain your UX then? What is the point of the `result` state and the form's `onSubmit` if you aren't using that in the UI? From what you describe I don't see how the solution I proposed *doesn't* do exactly that. Are you wanting the inputted prompt to *immediately* render and the POST resposne to later populate into it? Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: not sure if you took a look at my deployed site I posted above. Submit a few random prompt and you will see additional container being added into the webpage, which is why I have the addItem method. The only problem is the first submit, it doesn’t display the data that is fetched although it is fetched. Any submit after that, it displays the data. The solution you suggested removed that method. It getting late here right now. I will retry your solution tomorrow and see. Appreciate all the help so far.

Comment: @Jason I did take a look just in case I'd misunderstood or missed something. Right, my solution remove the `addItem` function and integrated its logic into the `onSubmit` callback so it could wait for the POST response that is added to the item in the `list` array. The behavior you describe is an `off-by-one` error where each list item is using the previously POSTed response value, this is why you don't see it for the first request made.

Comment: I will retry it again tomorrow. There’s a chance I might’ve missed something. I will let you know if it solve my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jason No worries. If you still have an issue though, if you can, please try to create a running sandbox example we can examine. Maybe it is just something trivial we overlooked.

Comment: I retried your code this morning and it did work! Only one minor change to your code. You had ```setList(list => [...list, inputPrompt]); ```, but it should've been ```setList(list => [...list, prompObj]); ``` instead, but overall it did solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Jason Oops, sorry about that little mix up. Glad it's all working for you now. Cheers and good luck.